# Magento 2 product save in store "0" instead of store "1" in single store mode

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

When I save my product, it saved in store view "0" (admin)

So the modification is not showing in the front-office.

But when I change the price, it directly changed in store view "1".

How can I save this product in store view "1" without change single store view mode ?

PS : I used https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool for migrate data to 1.9 to 2.3

Comment: I already had this really annoying bug after a migration, I had to enter all my changes in phpmyadmin in the `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table, what a hassle :(